# Not able to see the add variable wizard in mfc

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I'm using visual studio 2010 and i'M creating aN MFC dialog based application. Everything was working fine until recently when the add variable wizard stopped showing up when we right click on a control in main dialog and choose add variable.

I have 3 dialogs in the project. The add variable wizard shows up for the other dialogs. Only for the main dialog the wizard is not showing up, ie. nothing
is happening when we right click and choose add variable on say picture control embedded in main dialog.

I'm using 64 bit Windows 7.

Comment: Try closing studio, deleting the .sdf file for the project and reopen. The .sdf database can and does go bad.

Comment: VS 2017: there are no .SDF files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was ID mismatch(ID of main dialog) in the properties of dialog and the header of the corresponding class of the dialog. It is fixed and is working correctly now.

Comment: Thanks. It helped to me.